# Django messages framework: messages as strings

Tags: django, django-templates

I add a message like this in my view:

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.success(request, 'contact-ok')
```

How can I check for the presence of a specific message? I tried like this

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if message == 'contact-ok' %}
            alert('ok');
        {% endif %}                    
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

but somehow message can be printed like a string but not compared like a string and alert doesn't get called. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each message in `messages` is a python object, not a string. You can see the `Message` class in [`django.contrib.messages.storages.base`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/messages/storage/base.py#L12). You'll notice that each `Message` also has a `message` attribute, so instead of trying to compare object to string, use the message attribute of the object:

```
{% if message.message == 'contact-ok' %}
```